# WPF TextWrapping differences between ListBox and ContentControl

Tags: wpf, listbox, word-wrap

I have a listbox whose datatemplate contains a grid. Inside the grid I have a TextBlock, but I can't get the TextWrapping property works correctly: I wrote a sample to illustrate the behaviour:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyTest.Test"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Task}">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock MaxWidth="50" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=LongDescription}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">ContentControl: the textwrapping works as expected (select a row in the first listbox)</TextBlock>
    <ContentControl MinHeight="10" Content="{Binding ElementName=lsTask, Path=SelectedItem}" />

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">ListBox: I can't get the textwrapping work properly</TextBlock>
    <ListBox MinHeight="10" Name="lsTask" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskList}" ></ListBox>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">ListBox 2 : I tried with HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch": similar but doesn't wrap</TextBlock>
    <ListBox MinHeight="10" Name="lsTask2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ></ListBox>



    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">ListBox 3: I can wrap only setting Width in the datatemplate</TextBlock>
    <ListBox MinHeight="10" Name="lsTask3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green">
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Margin="3" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock  Width="200"  Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=LongDescription}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And this is my 
**codebehind:**

```
namespace MyTest
{

public class Task
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }

}

public class MyContext
{
    public List<Task> TaskList { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {
        TaskList = new List<Task>();
        TaskList.Add(new Task() { Description = "description1", LongDescription = "long long long long long long long long description1" });
        TaskList.Add(new Task() { Description = "description2", LongDescription = "long long long long long long long long description2" });
        TaskList.Add(new Task() { Description = "description3", LongDescription = "long long long long long long long long description3" });
    }

}


public partial class Test : Window
{

    public Test()
    {   
        DataContext = new MyContext();
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
}
```

In the ContentControl and in the first 2 ListBoxes I use the same datatemplate; in the ContentControl the WordWrapping works as expected (whenever I resize the Window), while in the ListBoxes it doesn't. What is the difference?

The only way I found to make the TextWrapping working in the ListBox is to fix the Width (or the MaxWidth) of the TextBlock, but it is not the desired behaviour.

Thanks,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListBox contains a ScrollViewer, so when the content wants to be wider than the ListBox a scroll bar automatically appears.  The solution is to disable the horizontal scrollbar.

```
<ListBox ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```